# Is there any way to link two user controls within a button event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

Now, I have two user controls, Login.ascx and CEF-Forgot-Password.ascx. I wanna button click event in Login.ascx, when it clicked, redirect to the forgotPassword.ascx. Is there any way to link those two user control within a button click event?
What I did is create an aspx webForm named forgotPassword.aspx and add the forgotPassword.ascx user in this form. The button event in Login.ascx redirect to the forgotPwd.aspx.
But it's not working.

Login.ascx

```
<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnForgotPwd(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Page.LoadControl("~/CEF-Forgot-Password.ascx");
    Page.Response.Redirect("~/forgotPassword.aspx");
}
```

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlHelper" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
<div class="dnnForm dnnClear">
    <div class="dnnFormItem">
        <dnn:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" ControlName="txtUsername" Suffix=":" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" MaxLength="200" 
            CssClass="dnnFormRequired" ValidationGroup="ICGCustomAuth"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UsernameRequred" runat="server" 
            CssClass="dnnFormError dnnFormMessage" resourcekey="UsernameRequired.Text"
            controltovalidate="txtUsername" ValidationGroup="ICGCustomAuth"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <div class="dnnFormItem">
        <dnn:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" ControlName="txtPassword" Suffix=":" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" MaxLength="200" 
            TextMode="password" CssClass="dnnFormRequired" ValidationGroup="ICGCustomAuth"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
            CssClass="dnnFormError dnnFormMessage" resourcekey="PasswordRequired.Text"
            controltovalidate="txtPassword" ValidationGroup="ICGCustomAuth"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>

    <ul class="dnnActions">
        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogin" resourcekey="btnLogin.Text" runat="server"
                OnClick="btnLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="ICGCustomAuth"
                CssClass="dnnPrimaryAction" /></li>           

    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li><asp:LinkButton id="Button1" class="btn bg-primary text-white btn-md pull-right" 
                Text="Forgot Password" OnClick="btnForgotPwd" runat="server"/>
         </li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

forgotPassword.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="forgotPassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebSite.forgotPassword" %>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="main">

        <uc1:CEF ID="CEF1" runat="server" />

    </div>
</form>
```

forgotPassword.aspx.cs

```
public partial class forgotPassword : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/CEF-Forgot-Password.ascx"));
       // CEF1.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/CEF-Forgot-Password.ascx"));
    }

}
```

Comment: When you debug and you click the button ````Button1```` do you hit the ````protected void btnForgotPwd```` event?

Comment: Also, I'd set ````CausesValidation = false```` on the ````Button1```` as you don't really care about any validation.

Comment: Javascript redirect